# Generating HMAC SHA3-512 in netcore2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, hmac, sha-3

I've already found some ways how to generate SHA3 in netcore 2.1. (e.g. SHA3.Net). Is there a way how to generate HMAC using SHA3-512 hash function. AFAIK it should be only some combination of SHA3(secret + content), but I can't find any working solution for HMAC based on SHA3-512. It's requested by 3rd party API I need to use, so there's no other option.

Result must be the same as result provided by this online tool (hash type sha3-512): https://wtools.io/generate-hmac-hash

Does anybody know how to generate HMAC properly for SHA3-512 under .netcore 2.1?

Thanks

Comment: [You can't yet](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16485). Implementing a secure hashing algorithm is *hard* which is why .NET Core doesn't implement the algorithms itself. It uses the underlying providers on each OS for this.

Comment: I don't think so, because SHA3 implementation already exists for .netcore and the only trouble is that I cannot find a way how to generate HMAC properly. So when you have hashing algorithm, you should be able to create HMAC. It don't have to be pure .net core. 3rd party libraries are welcome.

Comment: Since the HMAC functionality comes from the underlying encryption providers, one should expect that if you're using a custom library to shim in SHA3 support, you would need to rely on that library also for HMAC. In other words, there's nothing in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace that will HMAC using an algorithm not supported by that same namespace.  However, since all of this is ultimately just maths, you can create your own implementation, if necessary, but I would first try to find a library that supports both.